# AttributeError: module 'pygame.display' has no attribute 'setmode'

Tags: python, pygame

I have the following error:

AttributeError: module 'pygame.display' has no attribute 'setmode'

Code:

```
import sys
import pygame

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.setmode((1200,800))

run_game()
```

I already verified the following:

1. Latest Python and Pygame version installed
2. My file name is not pygame and I don't have any "pygame.py" file created in my entire PC
3. Pygame is installed under C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages
4. Reinstalling Pygame via command
5. Opened the test-game "py -m pygame.examples.aliens" in command succesfully to see if Pygame ran good
6. Saved my file under the Pygame package
7. print(pygame.version)
   print(sys.version) : Both show valid address and latest version

What could be happening?
I don't know what else I can do.
I am using Windows

Comment: just to add on @Baris Akin 's answer. visit pygame docs, they are written very good. https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead pygame.display.set_mode().

You have forgotten "_" between "set" and "mode"

```
import sys
import pygame

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))

run_game()
```

correct syntax!